# How to determine if application is ran on 64 bit OS? (Adobe AIR )

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, air, 64-bit, adobe

How to determine if an application (e.g. Adobe AIR) is running on a 64-bit OS? What function could one use to check this? (Code sample, please.)

I found one simple solution... Are there any others?

Comment: I am creating Air 2.0 native app. I want to use some programm that on x86 is in one folder and on x64 in another. Ofcourse I can literaly check if programm exists but it wount help any one but me=) So I wanted to determine it in general. Btw there is special function in AS3 for it but it does not work (tested - for me it always shows x86 while I'm on x64 ) ('flash.system.Capabilities.cpuArchitecture.toString();')

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adobe Air how to check if folder exists?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2869773/adobe-air-how-to-check-if-folder-exists)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the [Capabilities](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/Capabilities.html) class. You can get the OS, also there are many other details you can get.