# Adobe Air how to check if folder exists?

Tags: actionscript-3, air, adobe, filesystems, directory

Adobe Air (2.0) how to check if folder exists? (like folder C:\Program Files (x86) on windows) (code example needed, please)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you can use the following functions of the File class:

```
var folder:File = File.userDirectory.resolvePath(folderPath);
folder.isDirectory;
```

The `isDirectory` property will return a Boolean depending on whether or not that folder exists. Hope that helps,

debu

Answer (score 3):

```
 import flash.filesystem.File;

 var tempFold:File = File.userDirectory.resolvePath("FolderPath");

 if(tempFold.exists) 
 {
     trace("The directory exists.");
 }
 else
 {
     trace("The directory does not exists.");
 }
```